# Why is NTLM/kerberos used if we can use ldaps

Tags: ldap, kerberos, ntlm

Why do we use NTLM/kerberos if we can have a secure connection with LDAP using SSL.

Comment: This is like asking "Why do I need to lock my car, it already has seatbelts?"

Comment: you mean using NTLM/Kerberos to connect to ldap? your question is unclear

Comment: Yes, why to use NTLM/kerberos to connect to directory server, if we can use LDAP over ssl

Comment: @mathias can you please explain

Comment: I get what you're asking -- and, in some ways, there isn't a good answer because there isn't a reason to avoid LDAP over SS beyond "that's what we've always done" -- in a larger company, getting firewall rules adjusted can be a long, involved process ... it's easier to keep using what we got opened up ten years ago than get 636/tcp opened. Or change code to use the libraries required for LDAP. But the mechanisms provide different features -- I use Kerberos when the users are logged onto a domain so their existing credentials are verified instead of prompting for a user/pass *again*.